# How to display array of authors in laravel view file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display authors.where some books have one author and some books have 2 authors. How to manipulate this scenario
here is my html code

```
@foreach($books as $book)
      <tr>
        @if (json_encode($book['author']) !== 1 )
        <td>{{{ json_decode(json_encode($book['author'][0]),true) }}} &
        {{{ json_decode(json_encode($book['author'][1]),true) }}}</td>
        @else  
        <td>{{{ $book['author'][0] }}}</td>
        @endif 
     </tr>
```

But It is displaying only 2 authors but not single author.Any help or suggestions that would be appericated
Thanks In advance

Comment: You're checking for the response of json_encode. Instead, try `count($book['author']) > 1`

Comment: Getting like this  "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable" @aynber

Comment: What is the contents of  of `$book['author']`?

Comment: I mean it is saving array values in DB. i.e.["Auth1,"Auth2]

Comment: No, is it an array, an object, a Collection? `dd($book['author'])` or `Log::info($book['author'])` and show the contents.

Comment: It is in array format

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you have your tables setup but if authors are on a separate table as they should with a hasMany relation you should do this(assuming your relations are well formed)

**Book Model**, you described a `One to Many relation` between Books and Authors so you should use something like this:

```
public function authors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Author');
}

@foreach ($books as $book) :
    @foreach($book->authors as $author) :
       // do whatever you wish with all the authors here
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: could you dd($book) ?

Comment: how are your db tables? Have you setup a relation between books and authors in your Book Model?

Comment: I don't have table authors jus there is a column in books table

Comment: mmm so if its just a column it will always be in that column, the question is how are they saved within that column, if you don't show us that how are we expected to help?

Comment: You didn't even explain that on your question which is pretty **relevant information** you left out...

Comment: here is my controller code   $book->author= $_POST['author'];

Comment: how is that relevant wtf XD

Comment: come on man it will store the info what we given in input. input is dynamic multiple selction

Comment: if you store **all** authors on the same db column you will just have a field of text with authors, so you just can access it, what I'm asking is how is the data stored within the table, I don't understand why you showed your controller code, plus if you are using laravel why are you accesing $_POST variables like that instead of using Request $request? I highly encourage you to read documentation

Comment: $book->author = IF YOU STORE MORE THAN ONE AUTHOR HERE OR WATEVER YOU ARE DOING but you don't show how IT IS STORED how are you expecting any help wtf

Comment: Better to cool the discussion down a bit, guys. From what I can see, the easiest way for us to help would be if we knew what you store within `$book->author = $_POST['author'];`, which you can tell us by prepending `dd($_POST['author']);` and creating a new book. The output is what we need.

Comment: In DB it is storing like this @Namoshek ["AUTH1","AUTH2"]

Comment: You have a String, you just need to figure out how to extract both values from the String you can google some php methods to interact with Strings

Comment: Do you have `protected $casts = ['author' => 'array', /* other casts */];` defined on your `Book` model?